# Objective-c class or framework for formatting XML

Tags: objective-c, xml

Is there any Objective-c class or 'framework with utility classes' that can tidy XML received in a block into readable indented XML.

BEFORE

```
<Modules><Module><Description>Equities</Description><ModuleId>4</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Fleets</Description><ModuleId>2</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Futures</Description><ModuleId>5</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>News</Description><ModuleId>1</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Podcasts</Description><ModuleId>7</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Time series</Description><ModuleId>3</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Clients</Description><ModuleId>13</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Seanet</Description><ModuleId>10</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>S and P</Description><ModuleId>6</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Drycargo</Description><ModuleId>9</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>Tankers</Description><ModuleId>8</ModuleId></Module><Module><Description>MarketLine</Description><ModuleId>11</ModuleId></Module></Modules>
```

AFTER

.....

```
<Modules>
    <Module>
        <Description>Equities</Description>
        <ModuleId>4</ModuleId>
    </Module>
    <Module>
        <Description>Fleets</Description>
        <ModuleId>2</ModuleId>
    </Module>
...
</Modules>
```

cheers

Comment: I think it will take maximum 30 minutes to write such program on any script language or even on C. Isn't it?

Comment: Not that I know of but you could try using NSXMLParser with an NSMutableString to rebuild the xml with line breaks / indentation. You would know the indentation level by if an element calls the `beginparseelement` and `endparseelement` with the same element back to back.

Comment: seems TouchXML uses Tidy   https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the document and format it yourself. In your NSXMLParserDelegate keep an ivar `level` that indicates the current level or indention needed. Every time the parser parses a new start token, increase this by one and when it encounters an end token decrease it by one. Then, all you have to do is have a [`NSMutableString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and append the parsed nodes with the right amount of spaces in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple XML parser - overridden description method does full indenting

https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument

```
SMXMLDocument *document = [SMXMLDocument documentWithData:data error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",document);


<IndexPrices>
  <Index>
    <Change>109</Change>
    <ChangePercentage>3.15</ChangePercentage>
    <Description i:nil="true"/>
    <IndexCode>BCI</IndexCode>
    <IndexDate>2012-09-04T13:09:13</IndexDate>
```